# Running Katalon studio test suites on jenkins running on aws linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, katalon-studio

Can anybody help me how can i run my katalon studio test suites in jenkins aws ec2 linux instance. I am currently using Katalon studio on windows. The command to run Test suites on cmd works fine when jenkins is on local server but fails when i run the same command on jenkins on aws linux instance?